# Can text elements in Flash movies (SWF) use web fonts?

Tags: flash, webfonts

Is it possible to refer to a web font from a SWF, and have text in that Flash movie render in the style of that web font?

For example let's say I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="impact_label.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- The SWF object -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And in that stylesheet I have:

```
/* Generated by Font Squirrel */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ImpactLabel';
    src: url('Impact_Label-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Impact_Label-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Impact_Label-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Impact_Label-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Impact_Label-webfont.svg#ImpactLabelRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Pretend the SWF consists of one text element. Can I link out to the stylesheet, or for that matter any of the font files it consists of, and set the font-family of a text element in my movie to that of the external font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, fonts need to be in a special format for Flash.

If you want to load a font dynamically, you must embed it in a swf, e.g. `Impact_Label-webfont.swf`.  You can find complete instructions for that on [this blog](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/20).